# How to submit complex form in Node.Js + Express + Jade?

Tags: json, node.js, express, pug, form-submit

I have generated a long form with pairs of images. User is intended to classify image difference for each pair with bunch of checkboxes.

So, each checkbox is repeated multiple times and characterized by:

1) type of difference it means

2) left image name

3) right image name

How to collect all checkboxes data and submit it with one button to the server? How to encode data to send?

In plain web I would encode all parameters in checkboxnames and then decode them back on server side. May be Express + Jade has special means for this? May be I can get a JSON, describing all form filled and send it at once?

**UDPATE**

Currently I am to encode data into form field name, like here

```
<input type="checkbox" name="imagename1_imagename2" value="transitionname1">
<input type="checkbox" name="imagename3_imagename4" value="transitionname2">
<input type="checkbox" name="imagename5_imagename6" value="transitionname1">
...
```

and so on.

On server side I should do something like

```
for(var checkbox_name in req.body) {
   var pair = checkbox_name.split("_");
   var left_image = pair[0];
   var right_image = pair[1];
   ...
}
```

now, suppose that names require to be able to contain any character, so I need to escape/unescape them and so on.

Isn't there some tool to automate this work?

Answer (score 1):

You submit it like any other form. Assuming your code is set up similar to:

```
<form action="/example/handleFormSubmit" method="POST">
  <!-- Various generated form elements -->
  <input type="checkbox" id="example" name="example" value="example">
  <label for="example">Example</label>
</form>
```

Then assuming you've configured [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser), the form fields would be made available on `req.body`. So to get at the submitted data for the checkbox, I would do the following:

```
exports.handleFormSubmit = (req, res) => {
  // The `name` of the input field is also the property name on `body`
  console.log(req.body.example)
}
```

Comment: This means that each single form field turns to one single body field, and this means I still need to encode information inside name spelling which I want to avoid/hide.